# Enscript syncDataBase returns "07:46:10 [ERROR ] [4300] [14492] 0% HTTP request failed, code: 403, error: Forbidden"

Tags: enscript

I tried with and without credentials but same result. Worked fine last year.

I'm using Powershell to call the Enscript commands.

.\ENScript.exe syncDatabase  /l "$sti\log.txt"   #/d "xxxxxxxx" /p $pw /v | out-file  "$sti\log.txt"

I've tried both old and new syntax.

Had same problem with ExportDatabase. That appeared to have been removed from the commands, but SyncDatabase is still there, but doesn't seem to work. I'm using Evernote Legacy.

Any ideas?